# Single http session across multiple hosts?

Tags: python, http, session

Should you use a unique HTTP session per host a client program communicates with?

My current understanding of a session is that it caches relevant information for all requests sent in the context of that session. Is it O.K to use one session for multiple hosts, if those hosts expect similar contextual information? eg. (token, keep-alive, userid...)

I'm using python and in particular `aiohttp` though I don't think its relevant to my question, as I'm just after a better understanding of internet mechanics